# Time Sort with Parallel.For sorts only sub-groups of 8-elements

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C#, I used ParameterizedThreadStart to spawn 100 threads to sort a 100-element array of ints and it worked with a proper waiting resolution. Now Im trying same thing using`Parallel.For(start,end,ParallelOptions,delegate=>{})` but it is sorting only sub-groups and their length is no more than number of cores.

```
   float[] sorted;
    Random r=new Random();
    int[] toBeSorted = new int[100];
    //creating random integers between 25 and 75 for an array
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        toBeSorted[i] = 25+(int)(r.Next(50));
    }

    //target array of sorted elements
    sorted = new float[101];

    //Telling that it can use 100 threads maximum
    ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
    po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100;
    index = 0; // a static integer

    Object myLock = new Object();
    //time sorting. The lesser waiting elements are accumulated first. 
    Parallel.For(0, 100, po, i =>
        {
           Thread.Sleep(toBeSorted[i] * 100);//same resolution with Thread() version
           lock(myLock)
           {
               sorted[index] = toBeSorted[i];
               index++;
           }
        });

    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (float s in sorted)
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", s);
    }
```

Output:

29 44 45 48 50 54 56 44 65 59 45 73 32 59 34 46 28 45 71 36 69 36 44 46 45 40 72 74 70 62 53 30 39 55 30 48 29 32 64 45 66 38 62 66 48 47 46 57 45 33 62 32 48 58 41 47 55 53 28 52 28 63 46 44 32 31 29 61 41 55 31 54 48 74 37 38 39 51 59 68 65 40 31 37 40 37 71 52 66 45 25 74 57 70 59 74 70 54 72 69 0

**Question1:** How can I select minimum number of threads spawned or is there a hint that it should spawn maximum number of threads specified?

**Question2:** Can this sorting be worse than O(n) if upper and lower bounds of element are known?

May the reason not working be `parallel.for` is being a `data-parallelism` tool and not being  a `full-thread-parallelism` tool?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Adding lock(myLock){} and putting the indexing into this body, made sub-groups always 8-length which partially heals the sorting. Still they are sub-groups .

**Edit:** Using ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100); and max version worked but performance dropped for other parallel.for loops so spawning new threads manually seemed to be the better option.

Comment: Yay. Multiple threads doing things to `index` with no synchronization/locking.

Comment: ParameterizedThreadStart version was using a static one. Trying.

Comment: No change. Even with the `static`property, outcome is same :( There was no snyc in the other version but it was working.

Comment: _... to spawn 100 threads_ - that is silly. Parallel uses the correct approach: make all cores work with minimal nr of threads.

Comment: Just tried with a lock(){} mechanism and it made sub-groups always equal to 8-elements-long. But still there is only sub-sorted-arrays in 100-element array.

Comment: Looking again at what this is actually doing - *why* would you attempt to perform a sort like this?

Comment: Just for learning. Im learning the time sort and trying to make it some easier but it isnt getting easier. Only spawning many Thread()s is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parallel.For` uses the underlying `ThreadPool` to execute its work, which is why you're not seeing it spawn 100 threads. `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` only allows you to limit the number concurrent tasks to a number lower than how many tasks the runtime "had in mind", but won't dictate how many tasks actually get executed in parallel.

The static `index` increment only works by accident without a lock because of the large sleep gap between executing tasks.

Comment: Thanks. ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100); worked. But it made other parallel.for loops slow in the main program so I turned to custom Thread() spawning.